# PowerShell Comment based Help not working for script

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to implement Comment-Based help in a script I have written. I have tried to follow all of the documentation and guidance on this but I can't get it to work. Below is the format of my Comment-based help section:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Overview of my script

.DESCRIPTION

Description of my script

.EXAMPLE

Example #1

.EXAMPLE

Example #2
#>
```

My `param ()` section starts on the third line below `#>`. When I execute the command:

```
Get-Help -path .\Nameofmyscript.ps1
```

or

```
Get-Help -path .\Nameofmyscript.ps1 -full
```

the output is if I had just ran

```
Get-Help
```

Comment: to get realistic help, you will need to post the full code - stripped down to one that demos the problem. in the mean time, there is no `params` section ... do you mean `Param ()`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The above does demo the problem. I replaced what I actually had in the script with what is above and it generated the same result. Yes, `param ()` versus params

Comment: try with `Get-Help -Name .\Nameofmyscript.ps1`

Comment: the `-Path` parameter is not doing what you think. read `Get-Help Get-Help -Parameter path` for the rather confusing help info. if i use `Get-Help .\CBH_Test.ps1`, i get the expected nearly empty help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-Name` parameter here for your script:

```
Get-Help -Name .\Nameofmyscript.ps1
```

When passing a script name to `-Name`, you will need to include a full or relative path unless the script is within a `$env:Path` path.

Reading the documentation for [Get-Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?view=powershell-7), you can read a description for `-Name` and `-Path`. `-Name` is meant for a cmdlet, function, provider, or script. `-Path` accepts a provider path to display how the item passed into `-Name` works within the given provider. Typically, you don't need `-Path` unless you are loading a specific help file for a  provider.

Comment: this does in fact work but it also works without the `-Name` parameter. As @Lee_Dailey mentioned above, the `-Path` parameter was not doing what I thought it was doing and was in fact causing my problem.

Comment: The reason it works without `-name` is because that parameter is the position 0 parameter. So your value automatically binds to it if you leave it off. So you are utilizing `-name` in either case.